# 3d axis label ovelapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, labels

I'm using `matlab2tikz` to generate the `tikz` code for my figures. When compiling the document with the figure code as below, I get an ovelapping with the axis label y and z.

Here is what I've got:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
view={45}{-30},
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
xlabel={x},
ymin=0, ymax=10,
ylabel={y},
zmin=0, zmax=10,
zlabel={z},
axis lines*=left]
\addplot3 [
color=red,
only marks,
mark=o,
mark options={solid}
]
coordinates{
(1,1,1)(2,2,2)(3,3,3)(4,4,4)(5,5,5)(6,6,6)(7,7,7)(8,8,8)(9,9,9)(10,10,10) 
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there exist a way to solve it?

Comment: It is my first post here, it seems to be a great community, I've been reading some other post and found them really interesting.

Comment: `\figurewidth` and `\figureheight` throw errors. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). If I remove those two lines, the plot is compilable. Although the `pgfplots`' style is very different to your image.

Comment: I forgot to put them, now I added the MWE.

Comment: @Carlos Include the name of the user you are answering to (as I did now) so that they will be notified, that you have left them a message. If I compile your MWE, [all is fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q5yo.png). Is your TeX distribution updated? What version of TikZ/`pgfplots` do you use? Hint: [`\listfiles`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'm using Ubuntu and I just realised that Ubuntu came with an outdated Latex version, the `\listfiles` shows me that the `pdfplots` package is from 2010, I'm going to update it now.

Comment: If updating resolves your issues, please say so, so that this question can be closed.

Comment: Finally I updated my Latex version, it resolved my problem, now the plot is like the posted by @Qrrbrbirlbel.