# Axis label placement in 3d plot far out but why?

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to plot a dataset in a 3D pgfplots graph. It looks like a good start but somehow the label placement is far out. Boiling it down to a MWE did not give me any hints how to get the labels back in place. Is there any option I overlooked? My pgf and pgfplots version's are fairly recent, so it should not be this issue: [3d axis label ovelapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78849/3d-axis-label-ovelapping).

Here is my almost minimal example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
as_concentration    T   
0.00        0.0
0.00        0.152   
0.13        0.00    
}\ascycledata

\pgfplotstableread{
as_concentration    T   
0.00        0.152   
0.13        0.00    
}\asdata

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={45}{45},
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    ymin=-0.1, ymax=0.25, xmax=0.19, xmin=0,    zmax=0.3,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    axis lines=center,
    ]
    \addplot3 [forget plot,no marks,fill=blue, opacity=0.5] 
                     table[x=as_concentration,y expr=0,z=T] {\ascycledata}; 

    \addplot3+ [] table[x=as_concentration,y expr=0,z=T]    {\asdata};              
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

And the output with the axis labels far away:

[image: wrong result]

Comment: Looks like it's due to `axis lines=center` option.

Comment: Ah, that is already a nice hint. Some searching with this keyword revealed: "That is a known bug ..." by Christian Feuersänger (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84442/pgfplots-labels-and-width-issues-in-non-boxed-3d-plot-with-oblique-projection?rq=1). So that answers my question already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With percusse's hint it turns out that this problem is a known bug in pgfplots 1.7 (see: [pgfplots: labels and width issues in non-boxed 3d plot with oblique projection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84442/pgfplots-labels-and-width-issues-in-non-boxed-3d-plot-with-oblique-projection?rq=1)).

Christian Feuersänger already fixed this in the most recent unstable version of pgfplots (1.7-181-gc021eee). The fixed behavior needs to be enabled via the explicit use of the new version: `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}`.