# Naming 3D axes in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I want to label the axes in a 3D plot with `pgfplots`. Using the anchors `.right of origin` and `.above origin`, I can label the axes as "x" and "y" in 2D with ease. In 3D, the labels must be tweaked to appear in the correct place, and I have no simple way of labeling the x-axis. Is there an anchor that directly relates to these positions? The MWE below shows what I've produced so far.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%
[width=175pt,tick label style={font=\scriptsize},axis on top,
axis lines=center,
y dir=reverse,
name=myplot,
ymin=-1.1,ymax=1.1,
xmin=-1.1,xmax=1.1,
zmin=-1.1, zmax=1.1
]
\end{axis}
\node [right] at (myplot.right of origin)[shift={(-20pt,-8pt)}] {\scriptsize $y$};
\node [above] at (myplot.above origin) [shift={(0,-20pt)}] {\scriptsize $z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don’t you use the options `xlabel`, `ylabel` and `zlabel`? Although they are bugged in the current version ([Axis label placement in 3d plot far out but why?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100247)), this should be much better. To avoid updating you can use the `axis cs` coordinate system as in [pgfplots: labels and width issues in non-boxed 3d plot with oblique projection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84442). Not related to your question, but you might be interested in the `enlargelimits` option.

Comment: I didn't know the `xlabel`, etc., options existed (and I do read the manuals... apparently just not very well). I do get the bugs you alluded to; I'll see if the workarounds provided there help or will wait for a stable `pgfplots` update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), version 1.8, and

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
```

it is possible to use the options

- `xlabel`,
- `ylabel` as well as
- `zlabel`.

As you have reversed the direction of the *y* axis with

```
y dir=reverse
```

it is necessary to correct the position of `every axis y label` with

```
every axis y label/.append style={at=(ticklabel* cs:0)}
```

(previously `(ticklabel* cs:1)`).

In the example below, I have resized the whole plot so that it isn’t as cramped as before.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=2*175pt,
  tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
  axis on top,
  axis lines=center,
  y dir=reverse,
  name=myplot,
  enlargelimits=.1,
  ymin=-1, ymax=1, xmin=-1, xmax=1, zmin=-1, zmax=1,
  xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
  every axis y label/.append style={at=(ticklabel* cs:0)}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]